# Why does the SO Election Candidate Score Reputation more than Moderation

Tags: discussion, moderator-election

I'm a bit confused on why points are weighted so heavily in the candidate scores.
Candidate scores are used as indicator's for people to help evaluate the proficiency of the proposed candidate.

[image]

Reputation counts for 1/2 of the candidate score, While moderation and editing only count for the first time badge occurrence.  IMO this seems like a poor way to evaluate candidates.

While reputation is definitely important, should it really be the primary indicator of whether someone is a worthy candidate?

Shouldn't we be valuing edits and moderation task more than we do the score? Some metrics I believe would be more important to the election.

```
#edits
#reviews
#flag-raised
#numberHelpfulCloseVotes
```

Let's look at an extreme case, to depict the underlying nature of our elections:

If a user had 20k in reputation and has done edited 80 posts and raised 80 flags (the minimum for being a valid candidate)

Will get a candidate score of 23 (20 for reputation, 3 points for mandatory badges).

While a user with 3k, 20k in edits, 20k in reviews, 20k helpful flags raised, 20k in close votes, 1k wiki-edits, would only be able to tie the previous candidate score if they have every badge.

How does reputation accurately reflection ones ability to moderate?

My question is shouldn't we as a community value moderation tasks more than we view reputation.

Comment: Just get rid of the candidate score. Done! judge them on things other than a score, like how they handle themselves in meta/chat/comments.

Comment: @KevinB I'm with you on that, that would force users to do research on the canidates

Comment: yeah, but i mean, i wouldn't take the time to do said research, so i wouldn't expect a whole lot of others to do so either. we're just electing the cleaning crew.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Shouldn't we be valuing edits and moderation task more than we do the score?

Sure, but how can you do that without at least some reputation? Diamond moderators have surprisingly few extra buttons that a 20K user doesn't also have.

Reputation indicates that you are experienced on the platform. With very few exceptions, the effort it takes to get to 20K means you have to spend time here and learn how things work. You have to learn how to ask and/or answer questions. You have to learn how the community behaves and you have to interact with others. As you gain that reputation, you get new tools to help keep the site clean. That's what those badges and the other half of the score indicate.

Elections are not just a simple number. A 40/40 score doesn't mean that a user is going to be a perfect moderator, just as a 4/40 doesn't mean a user is going to be a horrible moderator. What it does mean, though, is that one user has more experience *here*. That number gives you, the community, and anyone watching a single data point showing how much experience a user has using very specific tools on Stack Exchange. The rest is up to you. If you depend on only a number, the job is done. But, most of a candidate's history is open to you via their profile. You can see the posts they've made, the meta discussions they've participated in and get a sense of how they interact with others by doing that research too.

Comment: I agree,  that reputation is very important, but maybe we can provide more metrics in the candidate score so user's have more information about their canidates

Answer (score 10):

The short answer here is that you don't even get access to the full set of moderation privileges [until you hit 20K](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user).

So from a practical standpoint, it's really helpful to have had 20K prior to being elected - you've already *had the opportunity* to make some of the hard decisions that moderators will face every day. Sure, review gives folks with much lower reputation a *taste* of this, but that's sorta like riding a bike down a paved trail with training wheels - you get a feel for what it's like, but there's still a lot to learn before you're going to be able to tear off down hill through the brush without falling on your face.

But there's more to it than that...

### Skinned

Let's have a look at what the expected duties of a moderator are here:

> 1. As a moderator, your actions now represent the community, so you will be held to a higher standard of behavior. You are an ambassador of trust, with the same sorts of rights that the official development team and community coordinators have.
> 2. Your goal is to guide the community with gentle — but firm — intervention. Respect your fellow community members at all times; demonstrate fairness and impartiality in your actions.
> 3. Whenever possible, try to leave frequent comments on posts where you’ve taken (or considered taking) a moderator action, explaining the reasoning. This is important so that community members can learn the norms of the community and the moderation policies.
> 4. Keep the site reasonably on topic by closing, migrating, or removing blatantly off-topic questions.
> 5. Regularly check for flagged posts, and decide if further action is warranted.
> 6. In the case of serious disputes, communicate directly with users via email to help mediate and resolve those disputes.
>
> -- [*A Theory of Moderation*](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/)

Notice how the majority of those duties involve *communicating with other people?* This is actually primary reason we **need** elected moderators: lots of other people can perform the editorial duties on the site, but it takes a special set of skills to calm troubled waters, enforce policies, and make hard decisions involving passionate, strong-willed *people* without making a complete mess of it all. And one of the best ways to learn that is... By teaching others.

It also requires a hefty amount of **mutual trust**.

Consider for a moment what would happen if we just hired people to moderate instead of going through all this election rigmarole. If all the moderators on Stack Overflow were 1-rep users that we'd trained to handle flags. How much faith would you be willing to put into a moderator's decision if they deleted an answer you'd written, or closed a question you wanted to answer, or contacted you privately about the language you'd been using in comments?

None. Zero faiths. You'd think they were a wage-slave who didn't care one bit for the goals of the site or the people who've worked to build it, and... You'd have every reason to think that: you've contributed hundreds of answers that help other people, while they've contributed nothing. Even if they had the best of intentions, **they have no skin in the game** - they wouldn't know what it feels like to spend time trying to help someone only for them to insult your efforts, they wouldn't have felt the sting of putting care and effort into a post only to see it deleted.

20K is a lot of skin in the game. They're not just moderating *your* site, *your* actions, they're moderating *our* site, and every action they take is a mirror onto themselves.

Now... 20K isn't a hard requirement, and certainly isn't a guarantee of any sort of behavior. We've had plenty of good moderators who got elected with less, and a few who weren't very effective with much, much more. But it's certainly not meaningless, and speaks to a candidate's ability and willingness to help others - which is what we're electing them to do.

Comment: If you become moderator and you have less than 20k, you still don't get the missing priviledges until you've earned 20k?

Comment: You get ALL the privileges, immediately @johnny5. And you get to learn to use 'em live in front of everyone.

Comment: "Consider for a moment what would happen if we just hired people to moderate..." <shudder> I've seen it in the Microsoft venues - disaster.

Answer (score 4):

This speaks to a major gap in information of *all* elections, not just SO moderator elections.

**If you want to back a candidate, you should do some due diligence in investigating them yourself.**

The candidate score is just a way to get the conversation started.  We've had similar metrics posted on other sites before but it was only formally codified into a score on the site.

If you want to know more about a person's moderation tendencies, then looking at what they've actually done to moderate the site is vital.  Showing that they meet a minimum standard of criteria is *fine* and, in my mind, enough to get you to take them seriously.

Comment: `If you want to back a candidate, you should do some due diligence in investigating them yourself.` Statement's like these give the appears of trust in all the user's voting.  While in there are definitely users who would vote on something superficial without doing research.

Comment: @johnny5:  Yes.  The problem with SO moderation elections is that they're almost popularity contests.  Sure, you find some great moderators in the pack, and you find some *really* bad moderators in the pack, but by and large they're almost always... *popular* in some capacity, which doesn't speak to their moderation prowess, *especially* for a site like this.  You ***have*** to do some digging yourself.  SO can only give you fuzzy metrics like scores and badges; you actually have to see if they have the chops to weather the storm.

Comment: I agree, but shouldn't we be taking the time to atleast try to create an election system that focus's on moderation

Comment: There are intangibles in moderation, much like in interviewing and interpersonal communication that no metric will ever be able to tease out.  How they act and behave on Meta is the most prominent example to mind.

Comment: interesting, maybe the real question I should be asking, is what can we do to help improve the Moderator elections

Comment: All I can say is... **pay more attention to the people running.**  That's about all any of us can do.

Comment: *but by and large they're almost always... popular in some capacity* That doesn't mean that's the reason people vote for them.

Comment: @BSMP:  I only have anecdotal evidence but there have been popular moderators who have easily made it through the primaries because they were popular.  You can't deny that there's a pile-on vote effect with their nominations if they see lots of other people voting for them either, *especially* with the pretty real-time graphs we can look at during the primary phase.  It may *not* be the reason that people are voting for those candidates, and I certainly hope that's true.  But that doesn't shake the very strong smell of it.